# A single expression that performs substitution and simplifies a trigonometric form

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I'm very new to Mathematica. I searched through the online documentation, but I don't understand why it realizes that $\sin(n\pi)$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ is $0$:

```
Refine[Sin[n*Pi], Element[n, Integers]]
```

> `0`

But not when I perform a substitution:

```
FullSimplify[Sin[2*Pi*f0*n*ts], Element[n, Integers] && f0 -> 1/(2*ts)]
```

> `Sin[n π]`

I tried using `Refine`, `Simplify`, and `FullSimplify`, I always obtain the same result. It looks like Mathematica somehow forgets about $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ at some stage.

Obviously, I've made a beginner mistake like using the wrong function or syntax, but I can't pinpoint the problem. So how should I rewrite the code above so Mathematica will both perform the substitution of $f_0$ *and* refine $\sin(n\pi)$ to $0$?

Comment: Use `FullSimplify[Sin[2*Pi*f0*n*ts] /. f0 -> 1/(2 ts), Element[n, Integers]]` instead.

Comment: another way is `Assuming[Element[n, Integers], Simplify[Sin[2*Pi*f0*n*ts] /. f0 -> 1/(2*ts)]]` gives `0`

Comment: @Carl, Nasser, indeed your solutions work. Thank you. But I had to restart Mathematica for them to work. Did I pollute the "variable space" when using `->` or `=` while experimenting in my previous session?

Comment: -> is equal to  Rule,it won't pollute the "variable space" ,but  = equal to Set,which will, so you'd better choose Block or With or Module.For example, to small test,x=5;f[x] is bad, f[x]/. x:>5 is better.(I know f[5])

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Would you consider summarizing that in an answer I could upvote and accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

summarize the comment

to solve this problem,we can `FullSimplify[Sin[2*Pi*f0*n*ts] /. f0 -> 1/(2 ts), Element[n, Integers]]` or `Assuming[Element[n, Integers], Simplify[Sin[2*Pi*f0*n*ts] /. f0 -> 1/(2*ts)]]`

besides,`->` is equal to `Rule`,it won't pollute the "variable space" ,but `=` equal to `Set`,which will, so you'd better choose `Block` or `With` or `Module` while using `=`.For example, to small test,`x=5;f[x]` is bad, `f[x]/. x->5` or `f[x]/.x:>5` is better.(I know `f[5]`) . The `:>` is equal to `RuleDelayed`